# Create JSON file from Ajax request with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I know there are lots of other similar questions all over, but I couldn't yet write the data from an object (a spreadsheet) to a JSON file.

This is my JS:

```
function (){
    var spread = $("#ss").wijspread("spread");
    var activeSheet = spread.getActiveSheet();
    var dados = JSON.stringify(spread.toJSON());

    activeSheet.bind($.wijmo.wijspread.Events.EditChange, function (sender, args) {
        console.log(dados);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'script.php',
            data: dados,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST"    
        });
    });
}
```

The data is sent to the console whenever there are changes in the spreadsheet, the file is created in the server but it is empty.

This is script.php

```
$myFile = "/file.json";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("impossible to open file");
$stringData = $_POST['data'];
$stringData=json_encode($stringData);
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to `json_encode()` the already-encoded data?

Comment: shouldn't you json_decode the incomming data?

Comment: I tried json_decode($stringData); as well but the result is the same: an empty JSON file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly don't know what the use of the double JSON encoding your script does is. I'll break down what actually happens for you:

```
var dados = JSON.stringify(spread.toJSON());
```

Assuming `spread.toJSON()` returns a JSON-formatted string as its name suggests, you will end up with a double JSON-encoded object representation by doing this. if `toJSON` returns an object, consider renaming the function, as it is highly ambiguous.

We'll go with the premise that `dados` now contains a proper JSON representation in a string.

```
   $.ajax({
        url: 'script.php',
        data: dados,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST"    
    });
```

You're sending to `script.php` (no news there), and **THIS** is where your first problem is.The `ajax` parameter is wrong as `data` contains your data, not the field `data`. This is done purposefully as to not obstruct access to parameters like `dataType` or `url` (which are pretty common).
Replace with:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: 'script.php',
        data: {
            data: dados
        },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST"    
    });
```

Note that the `dataType` parameter return will force you to return a valid JSON from your PHP code, or the AJAX call will fail.

**PHP**

Having made this modification, `$_POST['data']` will now contain your JSON-encoded object literal. The only modification to your code is the removal of `json_encode`. It is already encoded. You do not need any more of it.

I think what you were trying to do was to pass a request body to your code, at which point you would not have been catching it with `$_POST` but with input handlers (`fopen(php://input`)

Comment: Hi, thanks this was helpful! It is now creating the file although it has lots of backslashes in it, like: {\"activeSheetIndex\":0,\"sheetCount\":1,\"tabStripRatio\":0.5,\"tabStripVisible\":true,\"tabEditable\":true,\"newTabVisible\":true,\"referenceStyle\":0,\"useWijmoTheme\":false,\"canUserEditFormula\":true,\"startSheetIndex\":0,\"allowUndo\":true,\

Comment: @NunoNogueira: disable magic quotes or upgrade to a good PHP version, or just stripslashes() from the input.

Comment: Yes, stripslashes() did it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That's great. I was having this "\" issue and i was struggling to resolve this. Thanks for your comments  stripslashes()  resolved the same issue for me as well.