# Import JSON data to DOM error

Tags: javascript, json

I have a dados.json file that looks like:

```
[{\"activeSheetIndex\":0,\"sheetCount\":1,\"tabStripRatio\":0.5,\"tabStripVisible\":true,\"tabEditable\":true,\"newTabVisible\":true,\"referenceStyle\":0,\"useWijmoTheme\":false,\"canUserEditFormula\":true,\"startSheetIndex\":0,\"allowUndo\":true,\
```

etc...

My script is trying to importe this file:

```
function () {

var url = "dados.json";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    datatype: "json",
    success: function (data) {
            try {
                var sd //= JSON.parse(data);
                if (sd.length > 0) {
                    var spread = $("#ss").wijspread("spread");
                        if (!spread) {
                            return;
                        }
                        spread.fromJSON(sd[0]);
                        }
                } 
            catch (ex) {
            }
        },
    error: function (ex) {
        alert(ex);
     }
});
```

};

This is producing an alert message [object OBJECT]

I've also tried to remove the backslashes from dados.json but the error is the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your JSON looks like escaped JSON. How are you producing it?

Comment: Why is `JSON.parse(data);` commented out?

Comment: You can't inspect the contents of your error object with the alert function. That's why you're seeing [object OBJECT]. Make sure you are using a browser with a developer's console and do `console.log(ex)` instead of `alert(ex)` in order to actually inspect the error object. This may help you diagnose your own problem.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: I'm producing it with PHP. I've also removed the backslashes from it. You may see the whole script at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379305/create-json-file-from-ajax-request-with-php

Comment: That looks good but then why did your JSON become bad?

Comment: I haven't been able to remove the backslashes programatically. I did it directly on the file (Replace...). I have also not yet figured out why and wether they should be in the file or not.

Comment: `datatype` should be `dataType`, note the capital 'T'.

Comment: @Andy: `dataType: 'json'` tells jQuery to parse it for you.

Comment: Ah yes. I forgot that.

Comment: I got the stripslashes out using stripslashes() in PHP. I also corrected the dataType and tried both with and without the JSON.parse(data) and it didn't work. It did work, though, changing dataType to 'text'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON quotes are escaped and therefore jquery doesn't know how to read it. You shouldn't actually have to json parse it if you set dataType to json. What's producing your JSON?

After you remove the slashes, run your JSON through a validator http://jsonlint.com/

Then, right after your try statement in the JS console log data and see what you get. In the code you posed sd is just declared but not defined. Maybe replace it with data?

Comment: This is more of a comment, one that's been covered at that.

Comment: I'm producing it with PHP. I've also removed the backslashes from it. You may see the whole script at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379305/create-json-file-from-ajax-request-with-php
I haven't been able to remove the backslashes programatically. I did it directly on the file (Replace...). I have also not yet figured out why and wether they should be in the file or not.

Comment: The actual question in the question was "what am I doing wrong" and I think this kind of answers that, right?

Comment: when your remove the backslashes are there still problems?

Comment: I removed the backslashes by opening the file (Replace \ by "") and I get the same error. Therefore, in my initial post I assumed the backslashes were not the problem

Comment: Run your json through a json validator